# Button-toggles changes in height on IE11, when the user clicks on it

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a strange problem with Internet Explorer 11. Here I use a button toggle group in vertical direction and if the user clicks one one of the buttons in the group, the height changes a little bit (of the clicked button). The example code is based on [this source](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview):

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" vertical>
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

One button is rendered as:

```html
<mat-button-toggle tabindex="-1" class="mat-button-toggle mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard mat-button-toggle-checked" id="mat-button-toggle-1" ng-reflect-value="bold" value="bold" _ngcontent-yuh-c0="">
    <button name="fontStyle" tabindex="0" class="mat-button-toggle-button" id="mat-button-toggle-1-button" aria-pressed="true" type="button">
        <div class="mat-button-toggle-label-content">Bold</div>
    </button>
    <div class="mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay"/>
    <div class="mat-button-toggle-ripple mat-ripple" matRipple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"/>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

If I look into the CSS `mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay` and `mat-button-toggle-ripple mat-ripple` get a height of 52px instead of 48px. This increases the size of the parent element too.

I can disable the `font-family` attribute of `.mat-button-toggle` and on enabling it again the elements get back to their original sizes (48px).

What could be the reason for the change in height of the clicked button and is there anything I could do? This is only happening on IE.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You could put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like an issue caused by whitespace between the tags of the clicked button. Try removing all whitespace between tags and see if that removes the extra 4px. If that is the issue you may be able to solve it by using `display:block`.

Put this into your `styles.css`:

```
.mat-button-toggle-button { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please be more specific about what you mean with which tags? I added this CSS  `.mat-button-toggle-button { display: block; }`, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: What happens if you set `line-height: 48px` on `.mat-button-toggle`?

Comment: I think the issue is because the `button` element is an `inline-block` element - try setting `display: block;` on the button element and see if that works.

Comment: Setting line height makes it way too big. Regarding your second idea: If I set it in the css file it doesn't work. If I do it inline with the console in IE (F12) then the height doesn't change. Strange behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any chance that you could set up a jsfiddle that replicates the behaviour? It's difficult to diagnose without being able to see the code in action. Cheers.

Comment: You mean StackBlitz? Debugging in StackBlitz and IE11 is a mess ... But now I put my CSS `.mat-button-toggle-button { display: block; }` into `styles.css` instead of the components CSS and it seems to work!